# Rspec Authorization in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, http-headers

I'm developing a rails API, using rails 4, and I want to test it. To do it, I am using Rspec framework.

My API has an authenticate method that is called like this:

```rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 # Token authentication
 before_action :set_user, except: [:index, :create]
 before_action :authenticate, except: [:index, :create]
 before_action :authenticate_admin, only: [:index, :create]

 ...
end
```

Then I have my UsersController Rspec:

```rb
describe UsersController do
 render_views
 describe "GET /users" do
  it "gets all users" do
   @request.env["AUTHORIZATION"] = "Token token=xxxxxxxxx"
   @request.env["HTTP_ACCEPT"] = "application/json"
   @request.env["CONTENT_TYPE"] = "application/json"
   get  :index
   response.status.should be(200)
  end
 end
end
```

When I execute the test, it gives me always the same:

```rb
 UsersController GET /users getting all users
 Failure/Error: response.status.should be(200)

   expected #<Fixnum:401> => 200
        got #<Fixnum:803> => 401
 ...
```

I use authenticate_or_request_with_http_token method to get token from headers.

If anyone can help me to find the method to skip before_action method or to set the Authentication header correctly I will be very grateful.

Thank you!

Comment: We will need to see the authenticate method that I assume does your token authentication. Or maybe you're using devise or similar? One thing to check: you don't seem to be doing :authenticate on index (which is what you're testing).

Comment: Thanks for comment Jesse. I copied code but I forgot to copy the authenticate method for index that is:

  before_action :authenticate_admin, only: [:index, :create]

I use authenticate_or_request_with_http_token to authenticate.
Thank you.

Comment: I still need to see your authenticate method. It's going to take the token, and execute a find for your current_user, right? In addition, are you create a user with your token during a spec setup?

Comment: I use basic authentication. With a username and a password I create a remember_token that is saved in database. Then, in each request, the user must send a header : "Authorization" with value: "Token token=<remember_token>".

What I try to do, is to use an existing token from a user to access index method.

Comment: Where in your spec do you create the user?

Comment: I create with FactoryGirl gem, and it was the cause of my problem. I though that token was the same that the one getting from development database, and not.

Thank you for your help Jesse.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally solve the problem.

The error was that :

```
request.env["AUTHORIZATION"]
```

must be

```
request.env["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"].
```

Apart from that, I was getting a wrong token from a user that was not created in my test environment.

:)